# Python: Tweepy proxy_url issue: unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, proxy, tweepy

I do `pip install tweepy`
So I'm using whatever version that installs.

When I try `api = tweepy.API(auth, proxy_url="example.com:8888")`, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy_url'
```

Is there a new version of Tweepy or something? I saw that there was a fork that added a proxy_url argument, how do I install that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They right keyword argument should be 'proxy':

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, proxy="example.com:8888")
```

Comment: I get the same issue: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'

Answer (score 0):

So it was just a Tweepy version issue, I wasn't importing the right version of Tweepy that I had installed. welp